# Unable to INSERT data into MySQL through HTML form using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

**Here is my Form:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stats</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Member Information Form</h2>

<form action="submit_mbr_nfo.php" method="post">
    Member ID <input type ="text" name= "mbrid"/><br>
    Member Name <input type="text" name="mbrnm"/><br>
    Actual Name <input type="text" name="atlnm"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my PHP file:**

```
<?php
//Define database properties in global variables
define('DB_NAME', 'STATS');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Test');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

//store connection props in var
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

//check connection
if (!$link) {
    die ('Could not connect to the Database: ' . mysql_error());
}

//map $_POST to vars
$mbr_id = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['mbrid']);
$mbr_nm = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['mbrnm']);
$atl_nm = mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['atlnm']);

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO MBR_NFO '.'(MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) '.'VALUES ('$mbr_id', '$mbr_nm','$atl_nm')';

mysql_select_db('STATS');
$exe_query = mysql_query( $sql, $link);
?>
```

**And here is my php error log:**

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$mbr_id' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stats/submit_mbr_nfo.php on line 21
```

I am very new and learning PHP and HTML, i tried several online solutions but nothing has worked so far. I am able to insert into DB if I don't use $_POST, i.e., manually typing in the values in php code, but that's not the goal, the goal is to use Form to populate MySQL DB.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you are new and learning php then start learning `mysqli OR PDO` Because mysql is deprecated

Comment: you're right, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try following query

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) VALUES ('$mbr_id', '$mbr_nm','$atl_nm')";
```

Comment: this worked, however, it inserted blank values for MBR_NM and ATL_NM except for PK(MBR_ID).

Answer (score 0):

You are having issues with string concatenation and quotes. Try following query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) VALUES('$mbr_id', '$mbr_nm','$atl_nm')";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set primary key and auto increment on database for member id
so it very easy.you are not write mbr_id in query

$query="INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_NM,ATL_NM) VALUES( '$mbr_nm','$atl_nm')";

it's simple way

if you want not set primary key and autoincrement and try this code

$query ="INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM). VALUES('$mbr_id', '$mbr_nm','$atl_nm')";

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements (see below) instead of manually concateting the query string. But, since you’re new to PHP, let us first fix your code. The line

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO MBR_NFO '.'(MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) '.'VALUES ('$mbr_id', '$mbr_nm','$atl_nm')';
```

has a couple of flaws. In PHP, string concatenation is done via the dot `.` operator, which you have used only partly. In order to construct the query string `$sql`, you have to add a couple of dots:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) VALUES (' . $mbr_id . ', ' . $mbr_nm . ',' . $atl_nm . ')';
```

While this is valid *PHP* syntax, it is **still no valid *SQL***. If your user input is `$mbr_id = 42`, `$mbr_nm = 'amit'`, `$atl_nm = 'Amit Kumar'`, then after concatenation, `$sql` looks like

```
INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) VALUES (1, amit, Amit Kumar)
```

and is missing quotes around the strings `amit` and `Amit Kumar`. At best, this makes your query invalid; at worst, it makes your query [prone to injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1231686). Therefore, build your query using

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) VALUES ("' . $mbr_id . '", "' . $mbr_nm . '","' . $atl_nm . '")';
```

or, because in PHP, variables in [strings that are quoted with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) – e.g. `"my name is $name"`, but not `'my name is $name'` – are evaluated:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) VALUES ('$mbr_id', '$mbr_nm,'$atl_nm')";
```

---

By far the best practise, however, is [using prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1231686):

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=STATS', 'root', 'Test');

$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO MBR_NFO (MBR_ID,MBR_NM,ATL_NM) VALUES (:mbr_id, :mbr_nm, :atl_nm)');
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $mbr_id);
$stmt->bindValue(':mbr_nm', $mbr_nm);
$stmt->bindValue(':atl_nm', $atl_nm);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thanks, I tried all the above and nothing worked, I am still missing something.  Thanks for letting me know about the Prep statements and param queries, I will study those as well.

Comment: @AmitKumar In which way did it not work? Do you get an error (which?) or an undesired behaviour?